# Why does not Delphi save a custom component's nested property?

Tags: delphi, properties, firemonkey

(Firemonkey,XE7)
I have a component with TTextControl ancestor, introduced SizeConstraints, just based on the VCL version.
The designer does not save the Constraint property into the .FMX file.
When I look at the "view form as text" the constraint is not there, even if I edited the property values before (yes I can edit it in Object Inspector, but it's not saved)
What's wrong with this code?

Constraint definition:

```
TSizeConstraints = class(TObject)
...
published
...
    property MaxHeight: Single index 0 read FMaxHeight write SetConstraints;
    property MaxWidth: Single index 1 read FMaxWidth write SetConstraints;
...
end;
```

Component definition:

```
  ...
  published
    property Constraints : TSizeConstraints read FConstraints write SetConstraints;
  ...

procedure TMyComponent.SetConstraints(const Value: TSizeConstraints);
begin
  FConstraints.Assign(Value);
end;
```

And TSizeConstraints.Assign does copy the data:

```
procedure TSizeConstraints.Assign( const C : TSizeConstraints );
begin
  if Assigned( C ) then
    begin
      FMinHeight := C.FMinHeight;
      FMaxHeight := C.FMaxHeight;
      FMinWidth := C.FMinWidth;
      FMaxWidth := C.FMaxWidth;
      Change;
    end;
end;
```

What am I missing, or is it an IDE bug?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you derive from `TObject`. Derive this class from `TComponent` to get streaming capabilities. Or perhaps `TPersistent` as @NGLN suggests.

You should also change your `Assign` method to override the virtual `Assign` introduced in `TPersistent`.

Comment: Or derive from TPersistent (i.a. to prevent the need to set SubComponent).

Comment: Yes, TPersistent was enough - also looks cleaner in the Object Inspector (no Livebindings etc.). Thanks.